# Calling Make file in nested folder via Node.js

Tags: node.js, makefile

I have a complicated MakeFile file I want to call as part of my node.js app, the make file is a couple of directories deep from root. I know I need to spawn a 'make' chile process but moving node into the sub directory to call the make im not so sure about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сould you move the make to the nested folder? I would try something like

```
var util = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('cd samples/nestedmake && make',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

(copied with minimal changes from [Node Child Processes](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.0/api/child_processes.html) documentation).